# Can I enable a HDMI auto detect to substitute a GPIO screen

Tags: raspbian, gpio, hdmi, touchscreen

Ok so I am running raspbian jessie pixel on a pi 3 b and I have installed adafruits 3.5' piTFT and it uses the GPIO pins and I would like to know if I can cause it to auto detect HDMI on boot and oly use the PiTFT when it doesnt Or even both if necessary My Raspian version is the most current as of March 2017